# Rearrangement columns of a table in R

Tags: r

I have the following table that I want to modify

```
Debt2017  Debt2018  Debt2019  Cash2017   Cash2018   Cash2019  Year  Other
    2         4         3         5          6          7     2018    x
    3         8         9         7          9          9     2017    y
```

So that the result is the following

```
  Debt    Cash     FLAG After   Other
   2       5          0           x
   3       7          1           x
   8       9          1           y
   9       9          1           y|
```

Basically, I want to change the data so that I have the different years in different rows, eliminating the values for the year indicated in the column "Year" and adding a FLAG that tells me whether the data indicated in the row is from a previous (0) or following (1) year (with respect to the year indicated in the column "Year").
Furthermore, I also want to keep the column "Other".

Does anybody know how to do it in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(Debt2017:Cash2019,
               names_to = c(".value", "Year2"),
               names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)") %>%
  filter(Year != Year2) %>%
  mutate(flag = +(Year2 > Year))

# # A tibble: 4 × 6
#    Year Other Year2  Debt  Cash  flag
#   <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int>
# 1  2018 x     2017      2     5     0
# 2  2018 x     2019      3     7     1
# 3  2017 y     2018      8     9     1
# 4  2017 y     2019      9     9     1
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(Debt2017 = 2:3, Debt2018 = c(4L, 8L), Debt2019 = c(3L, 9L),
Cash2017 = c(5L, 7L), Cash2018 = c(6L, 9L), Cash2019 = c(7L, 9L),
Year = 2018:2017, Other = c("x", "y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Quick question, if instead I wanted to eliminate all the columns with a year higher than what is indicated in the column "Year"? I cannot put !<

Comment: @AndreaBrama do you mean `filter(Year > Year2)`?